# Disable orientation in certain View Controllers if device is iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I'm trying to make my app disable landscape orientation if the following conditions are met:

- The device is an iPhone
- The presented View Controller is `WelcomeViewController`, `LogInViewController`, or `SignUpViewController`

I've tried this in `AppDelegate.m`:

```
- (NSUInteger) application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window {

    if ( UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone ) {

        if ([[window.rootViewController presentedViewController] isKindOfClass:[WelcomeViewController class]])
            return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
        else
            return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;

    }
}
```

This doesn't work since I get an error, saying `Control may reach end of-non-void function`.

I also tried this:

```
- (NSUInteger) application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window {

    NSString *deviceModel = (NSString*)[UIDevice currentDevice].model;

    if ([deviceModel rangeOfString:@"iPhone"].location != NSNotFound && [[window.rootViewController presentedViewController] isKindOfClass:[WelcomeViewController class]]) {

        NSLog(@"I am an iPhone");
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;

    } else if ([deviceModel rangeOfString:@"iPhone"].location != NSNotFound && [[window.rootViewController presentedViewController] isKindOfClass:[LogInViewController class]]) {

        NSLog(@"I am an iPhone");
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;

    } else if ([deviceModel rangeOfString:@"iPhone"].location != NSNotFound && [[window.rootViewController presentedViewController] isKindOfClass:[SignUpViewController class]]) {

        NSLog(@"I am an iPhone");
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;

    } else {

        NSLog(@"I am NOT an iPhone");
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
    }
}
```

If I test it on an iPhone, however, it will go straight into the else statement, which is interesting, since if I remove `[[window.rootViewController presentedViewController] isKindOfClass:[SignUpViewController class]]`, it will work.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This doesn't work since I get an error, saying Control may reach end of-non-void function.

Well, think about your logic here (or lack of it):

```
- (NSUInteger) application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window {
    if ( UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad ) {
        if ([[window.rootViewController presentedViewController] isKindOfClass:[WelcomeViewController class]])
            return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
        else
            return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
    }
}
```

If `UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()` is `UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad`, you return something in every situation (both `if` and `else`). But otherwise, you don't say what to do! What if `UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()` is *not* `UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad`? What do you return then? Nothing! So this makes no sense. You are supplying insufficient information. You *must* cover every possible case, returning something *no matter what may happen*.

Personally, I think the entire way you are going about this is very silly. What I would do is implement `supportedInterfaceOrientations` in each of the three classes WelcomeViewController, LogInViewController, and SignUpViewController. In each implementation I would then express exactly what you said at the outset: return any orientation if the device is an iPad, but portrait only if the device is an iPhone. Yes, this involves some repetition — the implementation of `supportedInterfaceOrientations` will be identical in all three view controllers - but who cares? At least it will be understandable - and it will work, which is more than you've got going for you right now.

Comment: Oh yeah, that's right. I don't know why I didn't see that. I have some if statements elsewhere in my app where there is no else statement since I didn't need the app to do anything if it didn't match, so this didn't cross my mind to be honest. As for your suggestion to make one for all three ViewControllers, I'll consider it. Anyway, thanks for the answer.

Comment: Sure, my architectural suggestion is just a suggestion. But my way, you're so much less likely to tie yourself in these very sorts of knots, I think. Up to you!